# Unable to get Application using ServicePrincipal Credentials in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a Service Principal created which has **contributor** access. I have a user which also has contributor access.

When i login to powershel using ServicePrincipal credentials and run this command i am getting insufficient privileges error.

```
Get-AzADApplication|Select-Object DisplayName, ObjectId
```

When i login to powershel using User Credentials and run the same command i am getting the results.

```
DisplayName                                                                      ObjectId                            
-----------                                                                      --------                            
App1                                                                      XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX
App2                                                                      XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

in azure there are two kind of roles :

- Cloud resources roles ( contributor, owner, reader, etc...)
- Azure AD roles ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/ )

I guess that to run your command you need the second category and your principal is currently, as you said , only a contributor.

So you should assign an AD role to your principal based on what you need to do and retry .

Comment: Both the user and serviceprincipal has contributor roles. Then why does it work for user and not service principal

Comment: I guess that the user has also some azure ad role assigned

Comment: Try this command to figure out the roles assigned to your user
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaddirectoryrole?view=azureadps-2.0